# Python: How can I put the information I am scraping into an excel doc or a blob so that I can compare them whenever my code runs?

Tags: python, excel, screen-scraping, azure-blob-storage

I am attempting to scrape information on state supreme courts so that I can check when it changes. I am able to scrape and print the information successfully, but I am struggling to find a way to get it onto an excel doc or to another form of blob storage. Here is my current python code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Arizona_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Arkansas_Supreme_Court', 'https://ballotpedia.org/California_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Colorado_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Connecticut_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Delaware_Supreme_Court', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Florida_Supreme_Court']
for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    print([item.text for item in soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter a")])'
```

How can I get this into an excel doc or blob storage and refer to it later to check if information has changed. Thank you!

Comment: Please clarify what exactly the issue is. Stack Overflow is not a substitute for guides, tutorials and documentation, see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a few adjustments:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

list = ['https://ballotpedia.org/Alabama_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Alaska_Supreme_Court', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Arizona_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Arkansas_Supreme_Court', 'https://ballotpedia.org/California_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Colorado_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Connecticut_Supreme_Court', 
'https://ballotpedia.org/Delaware_Supreme_Court', 'https://ballotpedia.org/Florida_Supreme_Court']

temp_dict = {} #create empty dictionary

for page in list:
    r = requests.get(page)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    temp_dict[page.split('/')[-1]] = [item.text for item in soup.select("table.wikitable.sortable.jquery-tablesorter a")] #populate dictionary with state as key and the info as the value. 

# The next line does the following: create dataframe from dictionary,
# orient as 'index' (this handles different lengths of arrays) 
# transpose it back so state supreme courts are column headers

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(temp_dict, orient='index').transpose() 
df.to_csv('State_Supreme_Court_Info.csv') #saves as csv
```